# Moving your Projects and complete apps data from on computer to another

Tags: android, android-studio, key, alias

So I am planning to switch my laptop and want to move all the Android app projects and data from my old laptop to new PC.
I know I can copy and paste Android project folders and Key store files directly from one computer to another but what about Key Alias and certificates?

I don't know how to do that, and I don't think Google will accept updates to my old application unless I use the same key alias and certificates.

Please help.

Comment: You can use version control for code. Also, I don't think certificates are bound to a computer.

Comment: thats why googloe suggests to store your keystore file in separate place. Entering same information during creating signed apk should not create a problem. so just rememder keystore and those id password. thats enough i guess

Comment: @cricket_007 I was gonna say the same thing. Just you git for example, and when you're on your new computer just clone the repo and you're good to go AFAIK.

Comment: @Recomer Except you don't want to put everything in source control, such as your keystore and the passwords to it.

Comment: @nasch totally! But you can add them to .gitignore so that it won't be a problem.

Comment: @Recomer Correct, but then you can't just clone the repo and go, you also have to copy the ignored files over.

Comment: @nasch Depends on the things you've ignored I guess. And also you can just use a private repo and use vcs for whole project.